# Setting a background image with a button in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to set a background image to a webpage by clicking a `button`, mine isn't working, can anyone help?

Code-snippet:

```css
body input {
  background-color: #2c4c4c;
}
body input:active {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(meme.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styesheet.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <form>
      <input type="button" value="click me">
    </form>
    <!-- closing container div -->

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: just change it to background-image:url("meme.jpg") that should work

Comment: you should handle it with javascript

Comment: or make the button an anhcor tag <a

Comment: I had tried that, but for whatever reason it wouldn't recognize it.

Comment: replace button with <a> </a> tag

Comment: but the point is, I want it to be a button.

Comment: You can't change the css of a parent element using only css. You have to use javascript

Comment: You are setting the background-image of the button, not the page.

Comment: I noticed that later, still can't solve it though

Comment: The CSS part that's displayed

Comment: Hi! You try my "no" js answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You can't do that without JavaScript

Unfortunately CSS styles can only be applied to the selected elements and their children, neighbors, and siblings. Since the `body` is a parent of your button, setting styles on the button itself has no effect on it. You have to give your button an event handler that sets the background of the body tag. The easiest way to do it would be

```
<button onclick="changeBackground();">Click me</button>
```

Then create the function that will handle the click

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function changeBackground() {
        document.body.style.background = 'url(meme.jpg) no-repeat';
    }

</script>
```

Of course this is just the tip of the iceberg if you've yet to use JavaScript, [there's a lot of material about it on the web](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Comment: CSS can also be applied to neighbors and siblings, not only children/descendants. Good explanantion, though. +1

Comment: You're right, I am sleepy and oversimplify things to the point of non-correctness. Editing my answer. :)

Comment: Thank you this worked, I know javascript a little bit, but I was testing to see if you could do it with css, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="document.body.style.backgroundImage='meme.jpg'" >
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can do that without JavaScript!

Im found for a simple way to do that without any **Js** and you can change the triggering with html and css only. We need to change some html tags and simplest css code. The idea its to make our **"body"** container => (`#container`) and change him with background image.

**For example:**

```css
/* Making a fake body */
#container {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Hide the helper */
#helper {
  display: none;
}

/* On helper:active ~ change the next element (#container) */
#helper:active ~ #container{
  background: url(http://www.hutui6.com/data/out/207/68338774-view-wallpapers.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

input {
  background: #2c4c4c;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- helper -->
  <input id="helper" type="button">
  <!-- fake "body" container -->
  <div id="container">
        <form>
        <!-- trigger the helper -->
          <label for="helper">
            <input type="button" value="click me">
          </label>
        </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

**And one more option:**

```css
/* Making a fake body */
#container {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Hide the helper */
#helper {
  display: none;
}

/* On helper:checked ~ change the next element (#container) */
#helper:checked ~ #container{
  background: url(http://www.hutui6.com/data/out/207/68338774-view-wallpapers.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

input {
  background: #2c4c4c;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- helper -->
  <input id="helper" type="checkbox">
  <!-- fake "body" container -->
  <div id="container">
        <form>
        <!-- trigger the helper -->
          <label for="helper">
            <input type="button" value="click me">
          </label>
        </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

And [my Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/3p75vaos/)

Comment: I was Googling for what the OP asked for and came upon this Q&A. The URL you embedded for the fiddle is now a 404.